# Android Developer Documentation: download?

Tags: android, documentation

I'm on a slow network connection and it's painful to use the documentation at https://developer.android.com/guide/components/index.html.  Can I download the entire Android Developer documents to my machine and browse it locally?  This would include the documents for all of the various classes and other things.

Comment: Here is the ultimate answer [How to use Android SDK Documentation offline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66178613/13485979)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes you can.

Open SDK Manager (located in `android_sdk_dir/SDK Manager.exe`).

In the latest API (4.2) select `Documentation for Android SDK`.

Once downloaded, you can find the documentation in `android_sdk_dir/docs`.

Comment: Does this work for the training also: https://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Comment: There is no option to do this in Android Studio 3.6.3 on Ubuntu. How does one find the docs for offline use if SDK Manager does not list a download option for them?

Comment: Now you have to download "Source for Android XX" to get the docs (Android Studio Chipmunk)

Comment: Still cannot find after downloading source for android xx.

Answer (score 3):

> Can I download the entire Android Developer documents to my machine and browse it locally?

In the SDK Manager simply select "Documentation for Android SDK" for a recent API.

Comment: @Kumar Ha! We made the same correction at the same time.  Thanks for fixing it, I zoned out.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it under $ANDROID_SDK/docs/. If it is not already there download it via the  "Documentation for Android SDK" option.

Alternatively you can [download the source tree](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html) and link it up with your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

None of the existing answers works in new Android Studio versions.
But I've found that you can to go to `tools>sdkmanager`,
and check the checkbox that matches the API version you want (its status probably will show `Partially installed`). Then click `OK`. It will install the documentation automatically.

[image: screenshot of android studio sdkmanager]