# I can not find "Documentation for Android SDK" in sdk manager

Tags: android, sdk, doc

I have one problem and it is about find the "Documentation for Android SDK".I search in google and in this site and I find the solution about this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748558/android-developer-documentation-download)

but I can not find the "Documentation for Android SDK" in my sdk manager??

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio 3.3, the documentation is not mentioned under `SDK Platforms > Current API` but instead under `SDK Tools`.
[image]

You can reach this screen from `Tools -> SDK Manager -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK`

Comment: Mine does not have it under SDK Tools either. What to do? I am on Android Studio 3.6.3 on Ubuntu.

Comment: @RhetoricalRuvim I don't know, I haven't used Android Studio much since. But maybe it shows up if you uncheck the "Hide Obsolete Packages"? Would be weird though.

Answer (score 0):

It is part of the latest Android API level, which right now is 22:

[image: Android SDK Manager, with Documentation Row Highlighted]

Comment: thank you for all. The problem is something else. my sdk manager dose not display all of the lists. my sdk manager dose not load the new tools that is not available and not installed yet. when I go to the "https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository" by address bar I see the "404. That’s an error.That’s all we know. "  and also I see computer is being repaired as an image.

Comment: @stack: "when I go to the "dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository"; by address bar I see the "404. That’s an error." -- that is normal and is not indicative of a problem with your SDK Manager. If you go into Tools > Manage Add-On Sites, you will see the actual URLs that are used. You might consider trying the "Force https://... sources to be fetched using http://" option in Tools > Options. Or, click "Clear Cache" in Tools > Options, then do Packages > Reload to try reloading from scratch.

Comment: what about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63409366/no-documentation-in-android-studio-4-0-1-linux-mint

Comment: @user924: This answer is over five years old. Google apparently changed their system since then. I have never used documentation in the IDE -- this answer referred to a simple offline copy of `developer.android.com`.

Answer (score 0):

after downloading the Documentation from the SDK Manager like the pic in CommonsWare answer, you'll find the Docs inside: path.to/Android/SDK/docs (i have a Mac computer).