# Can I use Documentation for Android SDK offline?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I have a question.
I was googled how I can get API documentation for Android and open it offline (because my internet environment is horrible).
So I found some answers (which are few years ago), but those aren't working.

Here are links of them.

[link 1][Android Developer Documentation: download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748558/android-developer-documentation-download)

[link 2][I can not find "Documentation for Android SDK" in sdk manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29447091/i-can-not-find-documentation-for-android-sdk-in-sdk-manager)

They told I can download “Documentation for Android SDK” in sdk manager and I tried, but I think the location of that was changed.
And this is my screenshot:

[image]

Could you please help me? :(

Comment: @hata thanks for editting:)

Comment: Did you found out where to get the documentation at the end? I am having the same problem too